# efficient multithreaded algorithm to process a list of pairs without deadlock

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

Imagine that we have integer numbers from `0` to `n-1` (let's say that we have `n` images and identify them using this index) and a vector with pairs of these integers. It is not very important here how we create these pairs, but just to visualize the problem we may say that pairs are those images, which have common areas.

Our task is to process all available pairs using multiple threads. If the requirement was only that each pair can be occupied by a single thread, the task would be easy: we could use a mutex for each element of the vector with pairs. But in my case the situation is more difficult: if some thread processes a pair `(m,n)`, another thread cannot use any pair which consists of either `m` or `n`.

A simple solution to use mutex for each image is deficient. For example, let us say we have images `0,1,2,3` and pairs `(0,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,3)`, `(3,0)`. If the algorithm uses mutex for a pair and then two mutexes for each image, a deadlock is possible: `th_0` will process pair `(0,1)`, `th_1` - pair `(1,2)`, `th_2` - pair `(2,3)`, and `th_3` - pair `(3,0)`. Then each thread will use mutexes for individual images.

```
th_0: lock 0, lock 1
th_1: lock 1, lock 2
th_2: lock 2, lock 3
th_3: lock 3, lock 0
```

`th_0` will lock image `0`, `th_1` will lock image `1`, but then `th_0` will stop because it will try to lock image `1`, which is already locked. the same will happen with all other threads.

It seems that in order to achieve the goal each thread has to lock the whole vector with pairs in order to avoid deadlock, which does not seem to be a nice solution. Is this right? Is there a better solution to this problem? The only solution which comes to my mind is to use mutexes for images together with the thread priority information. For example, if the second image is locked, a thread will check if the thread ID of the locking thread is higher, then it should release the lock on the first image and proceed. Will it work or I can face a situation of deadlock again?

Comment: instead of locking `first` and then `second` of a pair you can lock `min(first, second`) and then another

Comment: How dense is the graph, in which each image is a node/vertex, and each pair is an edge? If it's not too dense, then you might get some mileage by 1) partitioning your pairs into equally sized non-overlapping sets using a minimum graph cut algorithm, each of which can then be run on a thread safely, and then 2) resolving the cuts / remaining pairs on a single thread afterwards.

Comment: Gruffalo, you may be right... thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gruffalo, why don't you write your idea as a normal answer?

Comment: @Paul, I have no particular problem in mind. I was just wondering about this issue since I have found out about situations, when deadlock is possible. But your idea is definitely interesting. Can't say however if it may outperform what Gruffalo has suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A deadlock happens when thread T1 holding resource R1 tries to acquire R2 while T2 holding R2 tries to acquire R1. Exactly your case.

The usual way to break a deadlock is to acquire resources always in the same order (if it's possible).

In your case "same order" is an easy solution: first lock `min(first, second)` and then lock another. So you'll never end in a situation when you hold a "greater" resource while trying to lock a "lesser".

While this solution is simple it can be suboptimal, depends on contention when your image processing takes long time and threads often wait for each other.

Answer (score 0):

Even without deadlock, many threads could be blocked waiting for next resource. This could lower the level of parallelism below the optimal level. To increase the parallelism level, you have to increase the number of threads, which require a lot of memory.

I see 2 ways out: 1) use some asynchronous task-parallel library, each task is to process some (n,m) pair. Since tasks use small amount of memory, you can generate all tasks at startup. Large amount of tasks promises high level of parallelism.

2) the best result, however, is to dynamically calculate the sequence of pairs which provide the highest parallelism level. It could be an algorithm running on a dedicated thread. It starts with generating N pairs (0,1),(2,3),...(N-2,N-1). Then it waits for the end of next task and looks if some other tasks can be submitted to the executor.